# Words syllables in php

Tags: php, string

guys I'm new in PHP, so please HELP! Thank you.
Lets say I need to syllable some, not typical words:
text= "abce dfia jicd fbii". 
Condition is: if we have two consonants near each other in text, like "bc","df","cd" or "fb", we need to split them with insert "-".
So output must to be: "ab-ce d-fia jic-d f-bii".
And my output is: "abcei-idfiai-ijicdi-ifbii". What I do wrong? Please help!

```
$text= "abce dfia jicd fbii";
$letters_1= array("a","e","i","j");
$letters_2= array("b","c","d","f");
$insert= "-";

    for ($x=0; $x<strlen($text); $x++) {
        foreach($letters_2 as $letter => $value) {
            if ($letter==$text[$x] and $value==$value) {
                $new_text= str_replace(" ", $text[$x].$insert.$text[$x], $text);
            }
        }
    }
echo $new_text;
```

I expect the output: "ab-ce d-fia jic-d f-bii"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is using [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to replace a sequence of two consonants with those two letters with a `-` between them.

```
$text= "abce dfia jicd fbii";
$consonants = array_diff(range('a', 'z'), array('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'));
$cset = '[' . implode('', $consonants) . ']';
echo preg_replace("/($cset)($cset)/", '$1-$2', $text);
```

Output:

```
ab-ce d-fia jic-d f-bii
```

Note that this code will only work for a sequence of at most 2 consonants, it there might be 3 or more in a row you need to call `preg_replace` twice. For example:

```
$text = 'abcce ibddfa';
$text = preg_replace("/($cset)($cset)/", '$1-$2', $text);
echo preg_replace("/($cset)($cset)/", '$1-$2', $text);
```

Output:

```
ab-c-ce ib-d-d-fa
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/uRANi)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a regular expression for this. As far as I'm aware, there's no shorthand for "consonants only", so we'll need to build that expression ourselves. Looking at the full `a-z` range, excluding vowels and using ranges where possible, that gives us `b-d`, `f-h`, `j-n`, `p-t` and `v-z` as consonant ranges (if you want `y` to be treated as a vowel, use `v-x` and `z` instead of `v-z`).

So something like this should work (there may be a shorter or more efficient expression to do this):

```
$new_text = preg_replace('/([b-df-hj-np-tv-z])([b-df-hj-np-tv-z])/i', '$1-$2', $text);

var_dump($new_text);
// string(23) "ab-ce d-fia jic-d f-bii"
```